# add important url parameter using htaccess rewriting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have this .htaccess url rewriting code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d                 -> important only if pagination is available
RewriteRule ^(article|gallery|news)/(.*)/(\d+)/(.*)/$(.*) index.php?page=$1&type=$2&id=$3&title=$4&page=$5&lang=en [NC,L,QSA]
```

this wroked for me and rewrite url like this:

```
mydomain/news/view/150/title.html/
```

and for pagination(important only if pagination is available)

```
mydomain/news/view/150/title.html/12
```

Now i need to remove `/` from end of first url Like This:

```
mydomain/news/view/150/title.html
```

How do fix this problem?!

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# no paging URL
RewriteRule ^(article|gallery|news)/([^/]+)/(\d+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?path=$1&type=$2&id=$3&title=$4lang=en [NC,L,QSA]

# paging URL
RewriteRule ^(article|gallery|news)/([^/]+)/(\d+)/([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?path=$1&type=$2&id=$3&title=$4&page=$5&lang=en [NC,L,QSA]
```

Also note that you have 2 parameters `page=` and I have renamed first one to `path` that you can change as you like.